# Why do LEDs have/need positive and negative nodes to function whereas say resistors don't?

Tags: led, breadboard, electricity

I'm very much a beginner experimenting for the first time with electronics, and I'm still trying to grasp the basics. On my breadboard, my LEDs have to be setup in a very specific way for them to work, the positive end being on the positive side and the negative node connecting to the negative side.

I thought the point was to get electricity to flow through the LED thus getting it to light up. Clearly electricity flows through my resistor even though it doesn't have a positive/negative node dichotomy. So why is it so for LEDS? Also if I may ask, what specifically causes one end to be negative and one end to be positive? What is the actual difference between the two nodes chemically?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it can easily be answered with a little Googling. Lack of research.

Comment: @LeonHeller I would cut him some slack. He is still at the point when he sees every component as a different kind of  resistor. Obviously wrong but not uncommon.

Comment: Have you heard of WIki?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-emitting_diode

Comment: @LeonHeller I tried googling it, maybe you can show what query would have been better. Because I tried variants of "Why are LEDs positively and negatively charged" or have "positive and negative nodes" and didn't find anything that explained the why, only that the longer end is the positive, or simply that LEDs are polarized. Which is why I posted here. Feel free to tell me a better google query

Comment: @user3002540 Not "negatively and positively charged", but"polarized".

Comment: ... the term you are missing from your vocabulary is "polarity" or "polarized". It's not a matter of "charge".

Comment: @vicatcu thank you for pointing that out

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 yes I've heard of wikipedia. I tried googling my question instead of reading the entire history of LEDs on wikipedia, next time I'll try that. I really didn't realize this was such an ignorant question to ask, I can't really convince you I suppose but I did try researching the answer to this question, it gives me no joy to post to this site and take flack from people. I'm trying to close/delete the question but it won't let me.

Comment: My posting your question 1st hit gave me 2 videos.   here's  1 . The best answer only follows a better question . The whole point of an education is to have enough wisdom to learn how to learn ,  a life long journey..  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zWC_AiycHbo

Comment: This is a good example of a novice question where more experienced members can come across as rude. It's a perfectly valid question and it is worth having _because_ it lacks "proper vocabulary" to help capture searches of other future visitors that also don't know the terminology. That said, it is always good practice to expend some time and effort researching topics before asking about them, and explain why your research was confusing or not helpful to you.

Comment: The secret to finding answers quickly is knowing how to find and use the "best" key words  by using a simple sentence ( without short words). Often iPad or  smart phone searches with voice using this method are faster than typing and sometimes give a better and sometimes "out to lunch" poor response. Learning where and how to learn comes with experience. My 11 yr old grand-daughter is so smart she says she doesn't even rely on parents to teach her values or recipes (ha) because she knows how to use You-Tube.. Read my profile if you want to learn electronics from links

Comment: @user3002540, if you do not know anything about an LED, then do not do specific searches such as `Why are LEDs positively and negatively charged` .... instead do a search such as `how does LED work` ... that should give you a bit of knowledge so that you can do more specific searches

Comment: @user3002540, there is some web content that explains electric current flow through wires in terms of water flow in pipes ... in the water based model, a diode is similar to a waterfall ... water can flow in only one direction

Comment: @jsotola Thanks for the advice. Yeah I've seen similar videos (water pipe analogy), I've spent a decent amount of time on youtube and the like. I suppose you're right I should have started with just "how LED's work" but I thought that might have been too broad, but you're right. That would have been more productive

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 thank you, those links look very promising. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 4):

Different devices are different. It doesn't matter which end you hold to swing a stick, but it does matter if it is an axe or baseball bat. Whats the difference? Symmetry.

For a diode, one end of it is made of P doped silicon and the other end is N doped silicon. A resistor is just the same material throughout. If the component is not symmetrical then it stands to reason it won't behave symmetrically either.

Comment: Sorry, I understand that it's different I guess I just didn't/don't understand why. I thought the current flows through which caused it to light up and I was just confused why the pins that connect to the breadboard couldn't be the same as the ones that connect a resistor. The phrasing I was using to search was poor, some of the answers here have given me a better idea of what to search. Thank you.

Comment: @user3002540 LEDs are not incandescent lightbulbs. They work very differently. Incandescent lightbulbs are basically resistors.

Comment: Semiconductor physics is a complex subject. If you want to understand the mechanics that give rise to polarity that's a course in electrical engineering, not a simple answer on stack exchange...

Comment: Yeah, the "why" for semiconductors turns out to be surprisingly hard to answer in a way that is both accurate and simple.

Comment: @pjc50 "Why is the sky blue?" is a question that quickly devolves into similar level of physics as semiconductors. The only difference is that we have a much more direct experience and thus intuition of the sky's blueness so most people tend to be satisfied with answers that don't delve quite as deep. Similarly, few, if any, students ask "what is a force?" or "what is mass?" in an introductory mechanics class but will always ask "what is a line of flux?" in an intro electromagnetics class. Having an intuitive sense of things seems to make people more comfortable with less rigorous answers.

Answer (score 2):

The "D" in LED stands for diode. Diodes allow current to flow in one direction but not the other. When (enough) current flows through the LED, it turns on.

In general, a diode is an p-n junction.

Comment: Ok, I guess that's my confusion, that's just the construction of the diode itself. I think "one way current" is what I was looking for googling "why do diodes only allow one way current flow" seems to be closer to answering my question, I probably should have thought of that phrasing. Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it.